# Why does assignment operator call constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, variable-assignment, smart-pointers

I am just playing around to understand smart pointers and trying to make mine but I come across a situation that I do not fully understand. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
template <class T>
class Holder
{
private:
        T * obj;
public:
        Holder(T * tt) : obj(tt) 
        {
                std::cout << "ctor : " << tt->dummy << std::endl;
        }
        T * operator -> ()
        {
                return obj;
        }
        operator bool()
        {
                return obj;
        }
        T * const get() const
        {
                return obj;
        }
        void reset() {swap(0);}
        void swap(T * other)
        {
                obj = other;
        }
        Holder & operator = (const Holder& holder)
        {
                obj = holder.get();
                return *this;
        }
        Holder(const Holder & holder) : obj(holder.get()) {} 
};

class A
{
public:
        int dummy;
        A(int a) : dummy(a) {}
};

int main ()
{
        A * a = new A(1);
        Holder<A> holder(a);
        A * b = new A(2);
        holder = b;

        std::cout << holder->dummy << std::endl;

        return 0;
}
```

The code compiles and on the line of `holder = b;` the constructor of `Holder` class is called. I thought compiler would give an error. It is not the assingment operator but why is it calling constructor?

Comment: `Holder` has two constructors, which one is called?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`holder = b` attempts to assign from `b` to `Holder`. `b` is of type `A*`, and `holder` is of type `Holder<A>`.

The `Holder` template defines assignment from another instance of the same `Holder` type, so the compiler looks for a **conversion** from `A*` to `Holder<A>`. It finds the constructor, and uses that.

Constructors which may take exactly one argument may be used for implicit conversions, **unless** you tag them with the `explicit` keyword.

Answer (score 6):

Both the constructor and assignment operator are called. You can check this by printing something in `operator =`.

This happens because `operator =` is defined to take a `const Holder &`, but `b` is of type `A *`. So first the `Holder(T *)` constructor is called to create a temporary object, then this object is assigned to `holder` through `operator =`.

If you define an `operator =(const T *)`, only the assignment operator will be called.

Answer (score 2):

I do not see a version of the assignment operator that takes a right hand side of A*

```
    A*        a        = new A(1);
    Holder<A> holder(a);
    A*        b         = new A(2);

    // assigning object of type A* to Holder<A>
    holder = b;

    // No appropriate assignment operator provide.
    // But a constructor is available to convert RHS parameter to correct type.
    // So compiler generates the following code:

    holder = Holder<A>(b);

    // There is an appropriate assignment operator for this.
    // So it compiles.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a constructor taking a T* .
Your assigment has a rhs pointer ,so it construct a temp-obj with that pointer as argument and assigns this to holder.